Can time series foundation models be used for classification?
Can time series foundation models like timesFM (https://github.com/google-research/timesfm?tab=readme-ov-file), which are designed for time series forecasting, be used for classification of time series?

Yes, you can finetune a pretrained model on a new task, assuming that you change the output layer to match whatever you are trying to predict.
And this works for any kind of model BTW. So if you have a pretrained LSTM for language modeling, you can just change the output layer to a Linear layer with softmax activation, and you get a classifier.
Then it's just a matter of training the output layer for your task
